# On Kubuntu how can I keep wifi connected when my laptop is closed?

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, laptop

I only use this laptop at home, and I would like it to stay connected when the lid closed so my dropbox and crashplan will continue to work during this time. How can I keep it from disconnecting when I close the lid?

Comment: when you close the lid, your PC goes to hibernate or suspension?

Comment: Ok but where can I change this?

Comment: mine was a question :-)

Comment: Oh I see...lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable lid close actions in all of the power management profiles:

System Settings > Hardware > Power Management > Energy Saving

and, in each tab, under "Button events handling" set "When laptop lid closed" to "Do nothing".

Comment: When an answer works, please don't comment: instead, mark it as accepted (green check mark below vote count), so we can see a) what worked for you, and b) the question has been answered.